# What's should I specify for the rootDirectory of an Azure Pipeline for a static website?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I manage a static website. No database, no server-side processing like ASP.NET (IIS), PHP, etc. This website is comprised of just HTML, CSS, some JavaScript, and a few graphic files. I'm trying to use Azure Pipelines for this. This is my first time using Azure Pipelines. I chose an HTML template to start the YAML pipeline.

I'm using the `FTP Upload` task. The source code is in Azure DevOps Repos. I'm testing the Pipeline by trying to FTP the files to a test folder on the hosting server (not a part of Azure). In testing the pipeline, I get this error:

> ##[error]Error: Failed find: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/bin/pyvenv'

I don't know what I should put as the rootDirectory. I thought it appropriate to put the "/". Here's the YAML:

```yaml
# HTML
# Archive your static HTML project and save it with the build record.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.sourcesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'ftp://ftp.destination.com'
    username: '$(TheUsername)'
    password: '$(ThePassword)'
    rootDirectory: '/'
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: '/test'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: false
```

What should I put for the rootDirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried
`rootDirectory: '.'`
OR
`rootDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'` ?

Comment: I believe `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` is the right starting point, and a `powershell` task that performs `gci $(Pipeline.Workspace) -Recurse` (and tolerating a lot of log output) could verify that.

Comment: I just tried `rootDirectory: '.'` which appears to work. I wanted the Azure Pipeline run. Could see the files being uploaded. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The root directory is your source code directory from where your compiled code is, in your case it should be checkout path.

I think you should use should use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/rootFolderName`.

Here root folder should be your repo name. You try printing the content of the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) to check whether you need to use $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) only or any nested folder inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The task `ArchiveFiles` field `archiveFile` default value is `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip`.

According to your YAML build definition, you have archived the folder `$(build.sourcesDirectory)` to the path `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip`, and next task is FtpUpload, then field rootDirectory should be `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip` and it will upload the zip file to a remote machine.

If you want to upload the static website, you could also set the field rootDirectory to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. Check the doc [build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) for more details.

Comment: Hey Vito, I don't want to upload a .zip file to the remote machine. The hosting company my client is using is Readyhost (ugh). The upload goes directly into the directory for the website. Nothing on Readyhosting is going to unzip it. And thank you for the additional details! I'm enjoying Azure DevOps Services.